# Typeable implicits not applied

Tags: scala, shapeless

Could someone please share some insight as to why the following compiles just fine:

```
import shapeless.Typeable._
import shapeless._
import shapeless.labelled.FieldType
import shapeless.record._
import shapeless.tag.@@

trait Typeables[L <: HList] extends DepFn0 {
  type Out <: HList
}

object Typeables {
  type Aux[L <: HList, Out0 <: HList] = Typeables[L] {type Out = Out0}

  def apply[L <: HList](implicit typeables: Typeables[L]): typeables.type = typeables

  implicit def hnilTypeables[L <: HNil]: Aux[L, HNil] = new Typeables[L] {
    type Out = HNil

    def apply(): Out = HNil
  }

  implicit def hlistTypeables[K, V, Rest <: HList]
  (implicit
   head: Typeable[V]
   , tail: Typeables[Rest]
  ): Aux[FieldType[K, V] :: Rest, Typeable[V] :: tail.Out] = new Typeables[FieldType[K, V] :: Rest] {
    type Out = Typeable[V] :: tail.Out

    def apply(): Out =
      head :: tail()
  }
}

object Testy {
  /** Typeable instance for `T @@ U`. */
  implicit def taggedTypeable[T, U]
  (implicit
   castT: Typeable[T]
   , castU: Typeable[U]): Typeable[T @@ U] =
    new Typeable[T @@ U] {
      def cast(t: Any): Option[T @@ U] = {
        if (t == null) None
        else if (t.isInstanceOf[T]) {
          val o = t.asInstanceOf[T]
          Some(tag[U](o))
        } else None
      }

      def describe = s"${castT.describe} @@ ${castU.describe}"
    }

  the[Typeable[Long @@ String]]
  the[Typeables[Record.`'test ->  Long`.T]]
  //  the[Typeables[Record.`'test ->  Long @@ String`.T]]
}
```

whereas commenting in the second last line `` the[Typeables[Record.`'test ->  Long @@ String`.T]] `` gives a compilation error:

`` Error:(56, 8) could not find implicit value for parameter t: Typeables[Long with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String] with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("test")],Long with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String]] :: shapeless.HNil]
    the[Typeables[Record.`'test ->  Long @@ String`.T]]
Error:(56, 8) not enough arguments for macro method apply: (implicit t: Typeables[Long with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String] with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("test")],Long with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String]] :: shapeless.HNil])Typeables[Long with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String] with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("test")],Long with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String]] :: shapeless.HNil] in object the.
Unspecified value parameter t.
    the[Typeables[Record.`'test ->  Long @@ String`.T]] ``

Using scala 2.12.3, shapeless 2.3.2.

I would have expected it to work with a record with tagged field types since I have provided a correct implicit def for any tagged type, and proved that it works by itself. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`T @@ U` is a synonym for `T with Tagged[U]`.

And

```
Record.`'test ->  Long`.T
```

is a shorthand for `FieldType[Symbol @@ "test", Long] :: HNil`.

So

```
the[Typeables[Record.`'test ->  Long @@ String`.T]]
```

can be rewritten as

```
the[Typeables[FieldType[Symbol @@ "test", Long @@ String] :: HNil]]
```

(whatever it means) and **this one works**.

So `FieldType[Symbol @@ ..., ...] :: HNil` and `Record. ... .T` are more or less equivalent syntaxes and obviously `@@` not always correctly works inside `Record. ... .T`.

(Here I used [Typelevel Scala](https://typelevel.org/scala/) and scalac flag `-Yliteral-types` for work with [literal types](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/42.type.html).)

Comment: Thanks for shedding light. > "obviously @@ not always correctly works".
Is your conclusion that there a bug in the record macro then?

Comment: @eirirlar
Well, I didn't check the macro. It's just a conclusion from your example. It's also possible that `@@` is not expected inside `Record. ... .T` notation. When you have two alternative syntaxes (for example `@@` and `Record. ... .T`) mixing them sometimes can have weird consequences.

Actually I guess I haven't met things like `Long @@ String` before. I guess I met `@@` with `Symbol` only, in things like `Symbol @@ ...`. Where did you get `Long @@ String` from?

Surely feel free to open a ticket.

Comment: For example if you work with strings rather than symbols ``Record.`"test" -> Long`.T`` will be just `FieldType["test", Long] :: HNil` or `Long with KeyTag["test", Long] :: HNil`.

Comment: `FieldType[Symbol @@ "test", Long @@ String] :: HNil` will be `FieldType[Symbol with Tagged["test"], Long with Tagged [String]] :: HNil`
or `Long with Tagged [String] with KeyTag[Symbol with Tagged["test"], Long with Tagged [String]] :: HNil`. Isn't it too deeply nested and nested in weird way?

Comment: `KeyTag` and `Tagged` are two different traits. I thought `KeyTag` was for `Record`s and `Tagged` for `Symbol` literal types. That's why I asked.

Comment: ```Long @@ String``` was an attempt I had for providing descriptions of the primitive types in my case classes without introducing custom types. I've since then resolved the problem in another manner. However I thought it was interesting that using @@ in a record definition failed like that.